# Accelerating python looping process for A-star path finding on DEM surface?

Tags: python, performance, loop, numpy, astar

I try to make an A-star Path Finding program base on tile-graph (image raster data as graph) where each pixel values represent as cost and elevation.. 
In my case, DEM raster data was called by using gdal, then converting to numpy array to be processed on A* path finding implementation.
This similar with Least Cost-Path analysis in GIS.

This is my standalone script i've been made so far :

```
    import gdal
    from gdalconst import *
    import numpy as np
    from numpy import savetxt
    import math as mt 


    def Input_Dem():
        filename = "F:\dem.tif"
        dataset = gdal.Open( filename, GA_ReadOnly )
        if dataset is None:
            print "failed"
        return dataset

    def Input_Cost():
        filename = "F:\cost.tif"
        dataset = gdal.Open( filename, GA_ReadOnly )
        if dataset is None:
            print "failed"
        return dataset

    def Weight():
        W = 1
        return W

    def RasterMatrix():  
        dem_surface = Input_Dem() 
        cost_surface = Input_Cost()
        DEM_Matrix = np.array(dem_surface.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray())
        COST_Matrix = np.array(cost_surface.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray())
        geotransform_dem = dem_surface.GetGeoTransform()
        geotransform_cost = cost_surface.GetGeoTransform() 

        col_dem = dem_surface.RasterXSize
        row_dem = dem_surface.RasterYSize  
        col_cost = dem_surface.RasterXSize
        row_cost = cost_surface.RasterYSize   

        cell_id_elevation =  dict(enumerate(DEM_Matrix.flatten(),1))
        cell_id_cost =  dict(enumerate(COST_Matrix.flatten(),1))
        cell_size = geotransform_dem[1]
        col = col_dem
        row = row_dem
        return cell_id_elevation, cell_id_cost, col, row, cell_size, DEM_Matrix, COST_Matrix

    def Var():    
        start_id = 1
        end_id = 151044
        open_list = [ ]
        close_list = [ ]
        current_cell_id = 0
        accumulated_cost = { start_id : 0 }
        parent_list = { }
        heuristic_type =  'M'
        return start_id, end_id, open_list, close_list, parent_list, accumulated_cost, current_cell_id, heuristic_type

    def adjacent_cell(o,dx,dy):
        adjacent_square = [o-(dx+1),o-dx,o-(dx-1),o-1,o+1,o+(dx-1),o+dx,o+(dx+1)]
        for i in range(dx,dy*dx+dx,dx) :
            if o == i :
                adjacent_square = filter(lambda n: n != o-(dx-1) and n != o+1 and n != o+(dx+1) ,adjacent_square)    
        for i in range(1,dy*dx,dx) :
            if o == i :
                adjacent_square = filter(lambda n: n != o-(dx+1) and n != o-1 and n != o+(dx-1) ,adjacent_square)  
        adjacent_square = filter(lambda n: n > 0 and n <= dx*dy,adjacent_square)    
        return adjacent_square

    def H(ht,y1,y2,x1,x2):
        if ht == 'M' :
            h = abs(x2 - x1) + abs(y2 - y1) 
        elif ht == 'E' :
            h = mt.sqrt((abs(x2-x1))**2+(abs(y2-y1))**2)
        elif ht == 'D' : 
            h = max(abs(x2-x1),abs(y2-y1))
        return h

    def Eucl_Dist(p,o,h,u):
        P_Eucl_Dist = mt.sqrt(u**u + pow((h[p]-h[o]),2))
        D_Eucl_Dist = mt.sqrt(2*u**u + pow((h[p]-h[o]),2))
        return P_Eucl_Dist, D_Eucl_Dist

    def Slope_W(p,o,h,u,w):
        P_Slope_W = mt.degrees(mt.atan((h[p]-h[o])/u))
        D_Slope_W = mt.degrees(mt.atan((h[p]-h[o])/mt.sqrt(2)*u))
        return P_Slope_W, D_Slope_W

    def F(p,o,h,u,w,c,dx,e_id,ht,CC):
        y1 = mt.ceil(p/float(dx))
        y2 = mt.ceil(e_id/float(dx))
        x1 = p - (dx * (y1-1))
        x2 = e_id - (dx * (y2-1)) 
        if o - dx == p or o + dx == p or o + 1 == p or o - 1 == p : 
            G = ( (c[o] + c[p])/2. + Slope_W(p,o,h,u,w)[0] ) * Eucl_Dist(p,o,h,u)[0] + CC[o] 
        elif o-(dx+1) == p or o-(dx-1) == p or o+(dx-1) == p or o+(dx+1) == p :             
            G = ( (c[o] + c[p])/2. + Slope_W(p,o,h,u,w)[1] ) * Eucl_Dist(p,o,h,u)[1] + CC[o] 
        F = G + H(ht,y1,y2,x1,x2) 
        return F


    def A_star(h,c,dx,dy,u,s_id,e_id,Op,Cl,Prt,CC,o,ht,w):
        Op.append(s_id) 
        while e_id not in Op : 
            candidate = { }
            for i in Op :
                d = {i : CC[i]}
                candidate.update(d)
            o = min(candidate, key=candidate.get)
            Cl.append(o)
            Op.remove(o)
            adjacent_list = adjacent_cell(o,dx,dy )
            for p in adjacent_list :
                if p in Cl:       
                    adjacent_list = filter(lambda i: i != p, adjacent_list)    
                elif p not in Op :  #
                    Op.append(p)
                    d = {p : o }
                    Prt.update(d)
                    d = {p : F(p,o,h,u,w,c,dx,e_id,ht,CC)}
                    CC.update(d) 
                elif id in Op :
                    f1 = F(p,o,h,u,w,c,dx,e_id,ht,CC) 
                    f2 = F(p,Prt[p],h,u,w,c,dx,e_id,ht,CC)
                    if f1 < f2 : 
                        d = {p : o }
                        Prt.update(d)
                        d = {id : F(p,o,h,u,w,c,dx,e_id,ht,CC)}
                        CC.update(d)

        def root_path(Prt, e_id) : 
                yield e_id
                while e_id in Prt:
                    e_id = Prt[e_id]
                    yield e_id        
        PATH_ID =  list(root_path(Prt, e_id))
        print PATH_ID

        PATH_Matrix = [ ]
        for i in xrange(1,dx*dy+1,1) :
            if i in PATH_ID :
                PATH_Matrix.append(1) # h[i]
            else :
                PATH_Matrix.append(0)
        return np.array(PATH_Matrix).reshape(dy,dx)


    path = A_star(RasterMatrix()[0],RasterMatrix()[1],RasterMatrix()[2],RasterMatrix()[3],RasterMatrix()[4],Var()[0],Var()[1],Var()[2],Var()[3],Var()[4],Var()[5],Var()[6],Var()[7],Weight())  

    print "path =", path
```

The result from this script is an array matrix representing a path connecting two location ( two cell ). For example (dim :25 x 29 ) :

```
path = 
    [[1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
     [1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
     [1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
     [1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
     [0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
     [0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
     [0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
     [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
     [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
     [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
     [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
     [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
     [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
     [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
     [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
     [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
     [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0]
     [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0]
     [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0]
     [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0]
     [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0]
     [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0]
     [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1]
     [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1]
     [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1]]
```

If i use a small resolution of DEM, 25x29 as an input, this program goes well. But if i try a large resolution of DEM, for example 1228 x 972. This program took very long time to calculate a whole cell. I guest that the problem is on the looping progress where i try to use loop for iteration (Line 110, A-star function).

```
 while e_id not in Op :
```

Is there any solution to make my code run faster ?

Comment: That's a lot of maths, perhaps this would be better tackled in C# (or even better C++) with Visual Studio. GDAL has C# bindings (and C++). Being an interpretive language python is really behind the 8 ball when it comes to intensive maths, a compiled langue will perform much better in that regard.

Comment: See a few answers on SO: [A-star search in numpy or python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14636918/327026) and [Elegant grid search in python/numpy](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13370570/327026)

Comment: Have you tried running your script with a [profiler](https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html#module-cProfile)? It might help you track down the bottleneck(s).